# Sharepoint online app, Access denied

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, access-denied

Hi I'm new to sharepoint. So I'm trying to develeop sharepoint online app. But there is an error here and I can't find how solve this issue. Error is :

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
>   access this resource.

App deployed to sharepoint online site. I wrote a script into `App.js`

```
function initializePage()
{

    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var context = new SP.AppContextSite(currentcontext, hostUrl);
    var web = context.get_web(); 

    var slider_list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Slider");

    //var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    //var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

    var user = web.get_currentUser();


    // This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
    $(document).ready(function () {
        getUserName();
    });

    // This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get the current users information
    function getUserName() {

        currentcontext.load(user);
        currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);

        currentcontext.load(slider_list);
        currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call is successful
    // It replaces the contents of the 'message' element with the user name
    function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
        $('#message').text('Hello ' + user.get_title());
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call fails
    function onGetUserNameFail(sender, args) {
        alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
    }

    function onSuccess() {

        console.log(slider_list);

    }

    // This function is executed if the above call fails
    function onFail(sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    }
}

    function getQueryStringParameter(urlParameterKey) {
        var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
        var strParams = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var singleParam = params[i].split('=');
            if (singleParam[0] == urlParameterKey)
                return decodeURIComponent(singleParam[1]);
        }
    }
```

But I get this error everytime which is wrote above.
I hope anyone help me.

Comment: Do you have full control over the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double Click your AppManifest.xml and hit the Permissions tab. Add the Site collection and request Full Control for your app

[image]